# spring boot + docker + kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

we have three environment as (dev, test and prod) and we have database configuration as below

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: ${URL}
    username: ${USERNAME}
    password: ${PASSWORD}
```

What i am trying is that i create the jar and then build the image and when deploying in to the kubernetes , i will be using the dev , test and prod respective deployment.yaml in which i will be loading the url,username and password to env so the application will read it during prod start up

So when i am trying to build jar application try to connect to the database and it failed to create the jar.

Please let me know my understanding is wrong or right if wrong then how to correct it and just one thing is that i can't change the process i.e jar+ image + kubernetes

Comment: Use configmaps to select the deployment environment. Mount them as environment variables named appropriately to match your `application.yaml`. Do the same with the database credentials, but use K8s secrets instead. You should end up in a situation where you have defaults (local dev for example) that get automatically overriden by environment variables on deployment using Spring Boots excellent configuration system. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/ https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: @BoristheSpider so you mean to say that by default i should have the url ,username,password for the local /dev so that during building of the jar it won't throw error but and later replace it in `deployment.yaml`
but the problem is customer does't want default url ,username,password to get committed .

Comment: Doesn't have to be local dev, doesn't even have to be defined - just needs to be valid Yaml. Having local dev details in there serves as documentation of what the variables should be called. You then just need to mount your credentials secret to appropriate environment variable to override.

Comment: One thing you haven't shared in the error that occurred during build.

Comment: correct that is what i am trying to do it but before creating the docker image i need to create the jar so that i can make the image .
but when i am trying to make the jar application try to connect it to `${URL}` and the creation of jar fails

Comment: You can use ConfigMaps to pass URL, but the best way to do this is DB URL as SPRING_JPA_DATASOURCE_URL to the container.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes you can put your configuration in Configmap or Secret. You can package the spring boot application and provide the Configmap entry as env variable of your container as exposed [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data)

Using Spring Cloud Kubernetes you can also read these properties without any configuration on the container as explained in this [article](https://link.medium.com/26PPT5XZYZ)